# Get a collection item by it's key

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a `Cake\Collection\Collection`:

```
object(Cake\Collection\Collection) {

    'count' => (int) 5

}
```

When I debug its `toArray()` output, I can see it contains an item with a specific key (say, *123*). So what if I want to get the item by that key directly, without converting the collection to an array?

- I looked through [/3.7/class-Cake.Collection.Collection.html](https://api.cakephp.org/3.7/class-Cake.Collection.Collection.html) and couldn't find anything that looks like a plain getter.
- `$collection[1234]` (of course) throws *Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Cake\Collection\Collection as array*
- `$collection->get(123)` throws *Fatal error: Call to undefined method ArrayIterator::get()*

So I then [searched for *CakePHP ArrayIterator*](https://www.google.com/search?q=CakePHP+ArrayIterator), found [the built-in PHP `ArrayIterator` class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php); it has [`ArrayIterator::offsetGet( mixed $index )`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayiterator.offsetget.php), which actually works as `$collection->offsetGet(123)`.

However, the above [collection doc page](https://api.cakephp.org/3.7/class-Cake.Collection.Collection.html) has no mention of `ArrayIterator`, so this feels like undocumented CakePHP usage. Am I doing it right? Otherwise, how do I get a collection item by its key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given how collections work you can't just access a key as you would in an array, the collection with all its filters, aggregators and stuff has to be evaluated first, and then a key can be looked up.

I don't know why exactly there is no shorthand method for fetching an item via its key, maybe because every collection is different, and the interface shouldn't be cluttered too much, but there's methods to filter the collection by key:

```php
$value = $collection
    ->filter(function ($value, $key) {
        return $key === 123;
    })
    ->first();
```

That would return the first item in the collection with the key `123`.

Using `offsetGet()` (or any other inner iterator methods for that matter) is discouraged, as it will not evaluate the collection! Say for example there's a filter on your collection that reduces it so that there is no `123` key anymore, using `offsetGet()` it would still return a value:

```php
$collection = collection([123 => 'foo', 'abc' => 'baz']);

$filtered = $collection
    ->filter(function ($value, $key) {
        return $key === 'abc';
    });

$value = $filtered->offsetGet(123);
debug($value);

$values = $filtered->toArray();
debug($values);
```

One would expect `$value` to be `null`, given that the collection has a filter that only includes keys named `abc`, but `offsetGet(123)` would operate on the unfiltered data and still return the value of the `123` key.

```
########## DEBUG ##########
'foo'
###########################

########## DEBUG ##########
[
    'abc' => 'baz'
]
###########################
```